# 1 year ArcGIS Desktop advanced student not working after formatting PC?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, license

I had ArcGIS 10.x installed in my PC and it was a student version for learning. I had to format the PC once and its just a month after installing ArcGIS 10.x but I cannot authorize it with the same code in the same machine. It but says its already authorized multiple times.

Comment: Please considers posting this question directly to ESRI-customer-support, since this is obviously a problem they can/should solve. Note on the side: Deinstalling authorized software (e.g. MS Office) before formatting sets the code "free" again.

Answer (score 5):

The student license will not work unless you de-authorized it before formatting your PC. You can contact your UNI or license provider and explain what happened. They can increase the pc count for your license and you can activate it again in your PC.